# Unable to install pgbouncer

Tags: linux, compiling

I am trying to install pgbouncer using source on RHEL 7.4. I am following [this tutorial](http://pgbouncer.github.io/install.html).

While running `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --with-libevent=/usr/lib64`, I am getting below error:

`checking for libevent... configure: error: not found, cannot proceed`.

However, running `rpm -qa|grep libevent` gives

```
libevent-2.0.21-4.el7.x86_64
```

and `ll /usr/lib64 |grep libevent` gives

`lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       21 Aug 28  2017 libevent-2.0.so.5 -> libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   297816 Jan 26  2014 libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       26 Aug 28  2017 libevent_core-2.0.so.5 -> libevent_core-2.0.so.5.1.9
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   179800 Jan 26  2014 libevent_core-2.0.so.5.1.9
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       27 Aug 28  2017 libevent_extra-2.0.so.5 -> libevent_extra-2.0.so.5.1.9
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   133864 Jan 26  2014 libevent_extra-2.0.so.5.1.9
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       29 Aug 28  2017 libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5 -> libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5.1.9
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    24464 Jan 26  2014 libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5.1.9
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       30 Aug 28  2017 libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5 -> libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5.1.9
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    11200 Jan 26  2014 libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5.1.9`

Unable to find out what is the problem.

Comment: `libevent-2.0.21-4.el7.x86_64` : That's only the run time files. You are missing the files required for compiling an application with libevent  → **libevent-devel**.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an Answer, @Knud!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> checking for libevent... configure: error: not found

`libevent-2.0.21-4.el7.x86_64` :

That's only the run time files. You are missing the files required for compiling an application with libevent → `# yum install libevent-devel`

Provides `/usr/{lib64/[libs].so, /include/{files.h, event/files.h, event2/files.h}}`